# Setting up autofac with webapi and an EntityFramework context & repository layer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, autofac

I am having some trouble with autofac and webapi, I think its due to my lack of understanding on the correct way to register them.

I have a repository layer using entityframework and standard type of repository pattern to interact with the database.

My repository layer, I inject the context via the constructor and also other repositories, in my example below I am passing in the customerRepository.

e.g.

```
public CustomerTransactionsRepository(MyContext context, 
                          ICustomerRepository customerRepository,
                          ILog log)
    {
        _context = context;
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
        _log = log;
    }

    public async Task<CustomerWithTransactions> FindCustomerSalesAsync(int customerId)
    {

        var customer= await _customerRepository.FindAsync(customerId);


        var transactions = await _context.Transactions
                                         .Include(c => c.CancelledSales)
                                         .SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CustomerId== customer.UserId);

        return transactions;
     }
```

My startup.cs configuration looks like

```
   private static void RegisterDependences(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<AifsLog>().As<ILog>().InstancePerDependency();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("MyNS.DAL"))
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerDependency();

        builder.Register(c => new LoggingActionFilter())
            .AsWebApiActionFilterFor<ApiController>()
            .PropertiesAutowired();

        builder.RegisterType<MyContext>().InstancePerRequest();

    }
```

When I try running the application, I get an error

> No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.

I think its due to using InstancePerDependency for my repository and InstancePerRequest for my dbContext.

Anyone else had this problem or can see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Wont the current configuration lead to Captive dependency? See blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency

Comment: What's the exception stack trace? Also, have you [read the docs on this topic](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html)?